# Userform entry validation

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with specific TextBoxes that I want to apply numeric rules only (no string entries).  I am having difficulties with creating an adequate error handler for this.  Essentially, because these textboxes are going to be used to perform a mathematical function, having string values causes the subs to crash and I cannot figure out the correct syntax to halt at string entries.

My current code is:

```
Private Sub TextBox12_Change()
    Sumdatup
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox16_Change()
Sumdatup
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox21_Change()
Sumdatup
End Sub

Private Sub Sumdatup()
Dim Total As Double
Total = 0
If Len(TextBox12.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox12.Value)
If Len(TextBox16.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox16.Value)
If Len(TextBox21.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox21.Value)
' Add more for the rest of your text boxes
TextBox26.Value = Total
End Sub
```

I had tried incorporating another sub to trap the string values from going through, but I continue to get an error tracing back to the first If clause in the Sumdatup program.

This is what I have tried that gives me errors:

```
Private Sub TextBox12_Change()
NumbersOnly
Sumdatup
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox16_Change()
NumbersOnly
Sumdatup
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox21_Change()
NumbersOnly
Sumdatup
End Sub

Private Sub NumbersOnly()

If TypeName(Me.ActiveControl) = "TextBox" Then
With Me.ActiveControl
If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Then
MsgBox "Only numeric values allowed."
.Value = vbNullString

End If
End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Sumdatup()
Dim Total As Double
Total = 0
If Len(TextBox12.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox12.Value)
If Len(TextBox16.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox16.Value)
If Len(TextBox21.Value) > 0 Then Total = Total + CDbl(TextBox21.Value)
' Add more for the rest of your text boxes
TextBox26.Value = Total
End Sub
```

The code never seems to check the NumbersOnly sub and goes straight to the Sumdatup code where it errors out when I try entering string values...

Any thoughts on how I might go at this a different way?

Comment: after they input the values, they need to hit a button to start everything, just run a `isnumeric()` and if it returns any false for any textbox, pop a msgbox and `EXIT SUB`... just do not do it with an `ONCHANGE` event, a decimal point may pop errors while typing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to do it on the run, you can do it like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox12_Change()
  If chkNum Then Sumdatup
  If IsNumeric(TextBox12.Value) Then TextBox12.BackColor = 16777215 Else TextBox12.BackColor = 255
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox16_Change()
  If chkNum Then Sumdatup
  If IsNumeric(TextBox16.Value) Then TextBox16.BackColor = 16777215 Else TextBox16.BackColor = 255
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox21_Change()
  If chkNum Then Sumdatup
  If IsNumeric(TextBox21.Value) Then TextBox21.BackColor = 16777215 Else TextBox21.BackColor = 255
End Sub

Private Function chkNum() As Boolean
  If IsNumeric(TextBox12.Value) And IsNumeric(TextBox16.Value) And IsNumeric(TextBox21.Value) Then
    chkNum = (Len(TextBox12.Value) * Len(TextBox16.Value) * Len(TextBox21.Value)) > 0
  End If
End Function

Private Sub Sumdatup()
  TextBox26.Value = TextBox12.Value + TextBox16.Value + TextBox21.Value
End Sub
```