# userform textbox required field-accept only a pattern of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I need help trying to make an excel `userform` `textbox` to accept only a pattern of numbers. My pattern of numbers are 12 digits.00.4 digits or 8 digits so the `textbox` should only accept a number similar to 772344456566.00.0001 or 77186238.
I have searched for clues to similar issues but none give me any direction.
My current code is this but not close to my target goal:

```
Private Sub Textbox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MsForms.ReturnBoolean)
 IF TextBox3.Value <>"" Or TextBox3.Value < 0 Then
      MsgBox "Invalid sales order number"
    TextBox3.SetFocus
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You say something about a 'pattern'... Do you only mean the string length by that? Would be "772344456566.00.0001" a kind of pattern? But you also say that the pattern must have 12 digits. Can you better explain what do you mean by 'pattern'? Should you say that the whole pattern must have 16 digits (dots included) and you try explaining it in words instead of only showing it? If yes, is it a second accepted variant involving a number of 8 digits?

Comment: @FaneDuru I think what OP meant was 'my pattern of numbers are; 12 digits, then ".00." then 4 digits'. Stand to be corrected though...?

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: Now I could see your answer, too... I also assumes that this is what he wants. But I looked to existing answers and started asking myself if my understanding is correct... I tried a clarification question, only to be sure, but he did not answered it. Since, it was not difficult to write a piece of code, after dealing with something urgent at the office, I posted an answer. It is very similar to yours. It was easier for me to test it without involving any `TextBox`...

Comment: My apologies. yes i meant for example this would be the pattern here: "772344456566.00.0001" or "72344456". so the first example is a total of 20 numbers with two dots, then the second pattern is just 8 numbers with no dots. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next function, please:

```
Function textOK(strText As String) As Boolean
    If strText Like "############.00.####" Or strText Like "########" Then
        textOK = True
    End If
End Function
```

It can be used in your code in this way:

```
  If textOK(TextBox3.Text) Then
    'do whatever you need
  Else
    'send a warning message... or do something else.
  End If
```

***Edited***:

You can test the above function in this relevant way:

```
Sub testTextOK()
 Dim x As String
  x = "123456787812.00.0014"
  'x = "12345678"
  'x = "123457j8"
  'x = "123456789"
  Debug.Print textOK(x)
  'or use MsgBox and comment the above code line
   MsgBox textOK(x)
End Sub
```

Please, un-comment from bottom to the top the `x` lines allocating values and see the return in Immediate Window (being in VBE: `Ctrl + G)...

Does it look now a little easier to understand how to use it?

Comment: This is a good and useful answer, but can you explain why you make a `function` rather than just put it all in a single `sub`? I assume there's a reason? I just want to know if I should be doing that more as well.

Comment: @Spencer Barnes: I tried explaining that in my answer to your comment... It was extremely easy to test it without involving any `TextBox` object, and to lazy in adapting it after... But, anyhow, I proceed in a similar way when (maybe) the same issue should be checked from more (let us say text boxes) other places.

Comment: I am not achieving any flag against the incorrect number wit the function example you provided. Maybe I am missing something here. Forgive me, I am still new to vba.

Comment: @Sam: Let me post a simple `Sub` to see how it can be checked. instead of `x` variable you can use your TextBox and deal with the necessary conditions...

Comment: @FaneDuru: I would like to have a look at the sub you said you would post. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sam: Refresh the page, please. I did it one hour before...

Comment: @Sam: Didn't you get it?

Comment: Yes. Thank you i received it.

Comment: @Sam: And didn't it work as you need? If it worked, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: @FanDuru: Thanks for the help, that worked. I also ticked the accept check box. I am still learning this but thanks for your direction.

Comment: @Sam:  Did you changed your mind, or played with the check box? I do not care about notoriety, but if possible I would like to understand what happens. If you changed your mind, not necessary to explain anything...

Comment: @FanDuru: I checked your answer and it did solve my problem. It did provide the flag against the number check I was looking for. i really appreciate the help and hope the check answer will provide guidance to someone looking for a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Textbox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MsForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Not TextBox3.Value Like "########" Or _
Not TextBox3.Value Like "############.00.####" Then
      MsgBox "Invalid sales order number"
    TextBox3.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

and/or have a look at [This](https://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator). Basically, when used with the `Like` operator, `#` checks for any digit, so `##` checks for a 2 digit number and so on.

Comment: Voted up, too... It was posted before mine. But I can swear, I did not see it before I wrote mine.

Comment: Thanks Spencer for the reference link to Like operators in vba.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be trying to reject values that are anything other than blank or negative.

Below is a selection of questions to review regarding validation of textbox forms in VBA.

[Validating the format of a userform textbox entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889340/validating-the-format-of-a-userform-textbox-entry)

[Validate textbox input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829436/validate-textbox-input)

[Making VBA Form TextBox accept Numbers only (including +, - and .)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and)

[Validating textbox entry on Userform (Excel VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010634/validating-textbox-entry-on-userform-excel-vba)

[Userform entry validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300301/userform-entry-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check the length of the value. Then, just break the value into separate parts and check each of them. Something like this (cannot check it as on Linux now):

```
val = CStr(TextBox3.Value)
len_val = Len(val)
If len_val = 8 Then
    If Not IsNumeric(val) Then
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
ElseIf len_val = 20 Then
    If (Not IsNumeric(CInt(Left(val, 12)))) Or _
        Mid(val, 13, 4) <> ".00." Or _
        (Not IsNumeric(CInt(Right(val, 4)))) Then
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End If
```

Comment: `CInt` will explode if it contains text characters. Besides, there's no need to convert to integer to check `IsNumeric()`. A simple string will do.

Comment: I am receiving a Compile error "Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return variant or Object".

Comment: @KostasK., I agree with your comment. Didn't have access to VBA to check the code, so I intended to show a general idea only.